# OnsenUI v1.2.1 にアップデート後、エラー

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

OnsenUI v1.1.4 → v1.2.1　にアップデートしたところ、

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION (native)
    at file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/******/www/components/loader.js:17368:28
    at completeOutstandingRequest (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/******/www/components/loader.js:6306:10)
    at file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/******/www/components/loader.js:6679:7
```

というエラーが大量に出るようになりました。

`$http` の通信開始後、返答が来るまでにエラーが出ているのは console から推測できましたが、何がトリガーになっているのかわかりません。どのタイミングと原因でエラーが出るのか特定できず、悩んでいます。

曖昧で申し訳ありませんが、なにかヒントでもいただけるとありがたく思います。

※ `loader.js` 内の `onsenui_all_min.js` を `onsenui_all.js` に書き換えた行数でエラーで表示されています

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: これだけだと、原因も推測しようが無いです。loader.jsの中は基本的に書き換えない方が良いと思います。